# Constructing an appropriate aov command in R

Tags: r, anova

I have some interlaboratory data where we have tested recovery weights of 3 different batches of product in three labs, with varying numbers of operators in each lab (see below).

I want to know whether the labs are all getting similar results.  Note that we expect the three different products to have different results.

My `aov` line is as below.  Is this correct ?

EDIT: I want to know if I have specified the model correctly for what I am trying to achieve. Apologies for not making this clear.  I.e. can I draw from this that all three labs are getting similar results ?

```
wt<-read.csv(header=T, text="
Date,Lab,Operator,Sample,Weight
05/11/13,L1,Op1,Prod1,0.42
07/11/13,L1,Op2,Prod1,0.58
08/11/13,L1,Op3,Prod1,0.95
30/10/13,L2,Op5,Prod1,1.77
30/10/13,L2,Op4,Prod1,1.02
31/10/13,L2,Op5,Prod1,1.67
01/11/13,L2,Op4,Prod1,0.73
05/11/13,L1,Op1,Prod2,0.06
07/11/13,L1,Op2,Prod2,0.18
08/11/13,L1,Op3,Prod2,0.42
30/10/13,L2,Op5,Prod2,0.66
30/10/13,L2,Op4,Prod2,0.34
31/10/13,L2,Op5,Prod2,0.24
01/11/13,L2,Op4,Prod2,0.73
05/11/13,L1,Op1,Prod3,0.12
07/11/13,L1,Op2,Prod3,0.14
08/11/13,L1,Op3,Prod3,0.3
30/10/13,L2,Op5,Prod3,0.8
30/10/13,L2,Op4,Prod3,0.04
31/10/13,L2,Op5,Prod3,0.2
01/11/13,L2,Op4,Prod3,0.08
01/01/14,L3,Op6,Prod3,0.16
01/01/14,L3,Op6,Prod1,1.23
01/01/14,L3,Op6,Prod2,0.10")

summary(aov(Weight ~ (Sample * Lab) + Error(Operator/(Sample*Lab)),data=wt))
```

(note in real life I have also done outlier tests and removed some samples).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about checking code.

Comment: @gung I'm not so sure about that: couldn't this question alternatively be interpreted as asking whether the model expressed in the `aov` command is appropriate for the given data and stated objectives?  As such the question looks to be on topic here.  Yes, it could be improved by restating it in a less `R`-centric way, but heretofore we have allowed many questions (and answers) that were expressed entirely in `R`-like language, for better or worse.

Comment: @whuber, I wouldn't vote to close a Q just because it's phrased in R terms. I interpreted this as 'is my `aov()` code correct?', which I consider off-topic, but I'm happy to have to Q here under your alternative interpretation.

Comment: @gung I guess neither of us is exactly sure what is being asked.  PJP, could you please edit your question to make it more apparent what you are asking for?